# Pass an array to a function and output each line

Tags: bash, shell

I was wondering if anybody could help.

I have the below code, it has an array of variables, `arr`, this is being passed to the method `outputArray()`, I require this to output each of the individual elements on their own line, when I run this code it only outputs the value of var1 and then finishes executing. The function does return a 0 or 1 (true or false) but this is functioning as expected anyway.

```
function outputArray() {
    for i in "$@"; do
        echo $i 
    # Condition omitted, this would manipulate data and return either 1 or 0
}

#Variable definition omitted
arr=($var1 $var2 $var3)
if outputArray "${arr[@]}"; then
    echo "True"
fi
```

I hope this makes sense, I don't post here often so please let me know if not and I'll try again.

Comment: Can you expand the example enough so that people can run it and see the problem you're describing? It sounds like you're using `return` in the loop rather than after it, and that's why it's only showing the first element.

Comment: Oh, the problem is that you have no `done` keyword.

Comment: This works for me (after adding the missing `done` and assignments to `var1` etc).

Comment: Me too: https://ideone.com/vcrhvB

Comment: The problem is almost certainly in the code you've omitted.

Comment: As an aside, consider `printf "%s\n" "$@"`.